# calculated property in Django model with QuerySet

Tags: python, django, amcharts

I am working on a frontend that consumes a Django backend.
I want to add a new calculated property to one Django model, that contains chart-data for amCharts.

After some research i found out, that using `@property` would be the way to go here.

However all the viewsets implemented atm use querysets, which as i found out after some googling ignore calculated properties.

1. Is there a way to keep the queryset and let it use my calculated property?
2. If not: Would manually writing out all the queryset operations solve the problem?

Code:

```
# models.py
class MyModel:
    # Normal props

    @property
    def calced(self):
        return somecalc

# views.py
class MyModelView(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return MyModel.objects.filter(id=self.kwargs['id_pk'])
```

Comment: You need to clarify this question. Querysets are for retrieving selected objects from the DB. Model instances are those objects. A model property is an object method. It can do anything at all, but typically most of what it does is concerned with manipulation of its own `self` fields.

Comment: Guessing now. Is what you want to do, to attach one or more fields from other related database rows to the objects retrieved by a queryset, to be used as inputs to the property calculation? That's called annotation. Consult the Django queryset documentation.

Comment: @nigel222 I want one additional field in the json, that is returned by the view, that contains the calculated data for an amChart. All the data needed for the calculation is contained in the model. I take a look into annotations.

Comment: You'll have to explain what is an amChart and how that relates to Django. If it's a Django model which `MyModel` can find by following one or more relations such as `ForeignKey`s, annotation is probably what you want. Maybe post the models and relevant fields thereof?

Comment: AmChart is a library for rendering charts based on a json-configuration. The frontend expects json-data in some property of the json returned by the `/api/mymodel/<modelid>` GET query. I can calulate the needed python-object with `@property`, but the queryset directly fetches from the db and ignores the `@property` methode.

Comment: If you show us the actual model and the calculation you're performing in `calced()` method, we might be able to see if you could retrieve this directly in the db query or not.

Comment: Otherwise, use a [`SerializerMethodField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) or a [`ReadOnlyField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#readonlyfield)

Comment: @dirkgroten Thank you. The SerializerMethodField was what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @dirkgroten i used the [SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) to add the new json-field before django ships my result.